# Erlenmeyer flask rinsed in StarSan

Tags: sanitation, yeast-starters, starsan

For the first time I'm making a starter in my Erlenmeyer flask.

I soaked, emptied, and drained the flask pretty good save the foam that is normal. The funnel, bung and blowoff tube were also soaked.

I pitched the yeast in a DME solution at 11-12 brix.

Pretty standard stuff.

Is there any risk I'm going to kill my yeast starter considering any residual StarSan present in the flask.

Comment: Nothing of what you said indicates anything out of the ordinary. Is there some *specific* reason that makes you think you killed it? The question seems like a total non sequitur

Comment: More of a first time yeast starter effort question. @FranklinPCombs, you should phrase as an answer. 

Comment: OK but what makes you think you've killed it? Presumably, if you're asking whether or not you've killed it, there's something that has led you to believe it may be dead and identifying what that is is key to answering whether or not it is, in fact, dead.

Comment: @FranklinPCombs nothing makes me think I killed it. Maybe I need to rephrase the narrative a bit. I literally just pitched the yeast in the Erlenmeyer flask. There is no way I could tell at this point obviously. I posited the question more to ease any worry I harbored as I considered my actions.

Comment: I totally understand your worries. I often feel a certain paternal-ness towards my starters too. It's just a tough question to answer because if there's no reason *you* think it's dead and nothing to indicate there's a problem, it's hard for anyone to give a better answer than "no".

Comment: @FranklinPCombs, rephrased question details to better explain any worry I was harboring about residual Star San in the flask as I pitched the starter.

Comment: Remember, if this will help another brewer, up vote the question too

Answer (score 2):

With StarSan (really, with *any* no-rinse sanitizer), as long as you're using it at the prescribed dosage and draining your vessel well, there's absolutely no danger to your yeast. There would need to be a *lot* of sanitizer (like dumping your yeast straight into the sanitizing solution) to have an effect on it. Even that probably wouldn't kill it, though it would taste nasty.

So basically, you're fine. Just watch it bubble away.